# How to assign fixed background-image with respect to a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used fixed background images in my carousel of website made with bootstrap. The background images are fixed to show the parallaxing effect. But the problem is the when new slides of carouslel move to left the image already present there remains fixed. What I want is that the background image on a div move when the div moves with css transition effects.

I want this type of carousel http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp In other words I want the `next item` to push the background image of `active item` to the left. At present when the `next item` slides to the left it opaques the `current item`'s background image.

The code is as following:

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 320px)");
var mylogo = document.getElementById("mylogo");
if (mq.matches) {
  mylogo.innerHTML = "SSR";
}

function changelogo() {
  return function() {
    if (mq.matches) {

      mylogo.innerHTML = "SSR";
    } else {
      mylogo.innerHTML = "Syco Scientist Records"
    }
  }
}

window.onresize = changelogo();

if (window.matchMedia("(max-height: 420px)").matches) {
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("item")[n].style.backgroundSize = "100% calc(100% - 140px)";
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 60px;
  border-color: #333;
  background-color: #d6d5d5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 14px;
  border-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle > .icon-bar {
  background-color: #333;
}
.navbar ul.navbar-nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li > a {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li.active > a,
.navbar ul.nav > li.active:hover > a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #d6d5d5;
}
#home {
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 6;
}
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 420px;
}
.mobile-carousel {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.71, -0.06, .36, 1.35);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.71, -0.06, .36, 1.35);
}
.carousel-inner .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 568px;
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .first {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_OdCx7pACI9M/TQhDqhnKXgI/AAAAAAAAAH8/kPDpkHpFOnw/s1600/daffy+duck+cartoons+pictures+1.gif) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-inner .second {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://www.allgraphics123.com/graphics/cartoons/cartoons123.gif) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-inner .third {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/211/WDF_2483525.png) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-inner .fourth {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/109/WDF_1525343.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-control span {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.carousel-control span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -9px;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #777;
  border: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #dcdbdb;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Syco Scientist Records</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="mylogo"> Syco Sientist Records </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="home">
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="container-fluid mobile-carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>

          <div class="item active first"></div>
          <div class="item second"></div>
          <div class="item third"></div>
          <div class="item fourth"></div>

          <a href="#mycarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/left_Arrow.png"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#mycarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/right_arrow.png"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

How do I acheive this?

**Edit:** It seems like the problem is only in firefox browser. Please explain why it works in chrome browser and not in firefox browser.

Comment: can you please explain more.. I didn't understand..sorry

Comment: @sagarkodte I've added a second paragraph to explain further what I want. If any point is not clear then please ask; I'll explain it further.

Comment: @user31782 Please look at this screencapture: http://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NjU4MTM3XzMxNzM3MTU What you described is what it's doing I believe. I removed two things: the shiv and respond.js. This is on Chrome, the issue is with Firefox, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne I didn't know that it works fine in chrome. Which is strange because background-image is fixed with respect to the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this . carousel next item will appear on previous item after that the background image of active item to the left

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 320px)");
var mylogo = document.getElementById("mylogo");
if (mq.matches) {
  mylogo.innerHTML = "SSR";
}

function changelogo() {
  return function() {
    if (mq.matches) {

      mylogo.innerHTML = "SSR";
    } else {
      mylogo.innerHTML = "Syco Scientist Records"
    }
  }
}

window.onresize = changelogo();

if (window.matchMedia("(max-height: 420px)").matches) {
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("item")[n].style.backgroundSize = "100% calc(100% - 140px)";
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 60px;
  border-color: #333;
  background-color: #d6d5d5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 14px;
  border-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle > .icon-bar {
  background-color: #333;
}
.navbar ul.navbar-nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li > a {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li.active > a,
.navbar ul.nav > li.active:hover > a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #d6d5d5;
}
#home {
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 6;
}
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 420px;
}
.mobile-carousel {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.71, -0.06, .36, 1.35);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.71, -0.06, .36, 1.35);
}
.carousel-inner .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 568px;
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .first {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_OdCx7pACI9M/TQhDqhnKXgI/AAAAAAAAAH8/kPDpkHpFOnw/s1600/daffy+duck+cartoons+pictures+1.gif) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
transform: none !important;
-webkit-transform: none !important;
}
.carousel-inner .second {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://www.allgraphics123.com/graphics/cartoons/cartoons123.gif) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
transform: none !important;
-webkit-transform: none !important;
}
.carousel-inner .third {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/211/WDF_2483525.png) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
 backface-visibility: visible !important;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
transform: none !important;
-webkit-transform: none !important;
}
.carousel-inner .fourth {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/109/WDF_1525343.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
transform: none !important;
-webkit-transform: none !important;
}
.carousel-control span {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.carousel-control span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -9px;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #777;
  border: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #dcdbdb;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Syco Scientist Records</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="mylogo"> Syco Sientist Records </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="home">
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="container-fluid mobile-carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>

          <div class="item active first"></div>
          <div class="item second"></div>
          <div class="item third"></div>
          <div class="item fourth"></div>

          <a href="#mycarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/left_Arrow.png"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#mycarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/right_arrow.png"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please look at this screencapture: https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NjU4MTM3XzMxNzM3MTU What you described is what it's doing I believe. I removed two things: the shiv and respond.js. This is on Chrome, the issue is with Firefox, correct?

Comment: i saw that link .  now i came to understand the requirement

Comment: My bad I thought this was the OP's comment panel.

Comment: by basing on your link zee00ne check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramachandra/cdLqroqk/1/) here i m  not used .js

Comment: I'm not the OP, and I'm not 100% sure what the OP wanted, but the behavior for Chrome looks right and on Firefox it doesn't. I'm guessing that the OP wants what Chrome does, which still leaves Firefox to be fixed.

Comment: transition timing function is supported to firefox versions 4.0 (2.0)-moz
16.0 (16.0)  and the different browser compatibility for transition (-webkit- (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera.)
-moz- (Firefox)
-o- (Old versions of Opera)
-ms- (Internet Explorer)  [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this css :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Syco Scientist Records</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <style>
        div#mycarousel .carousel-inner .item{
            padding:0 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="mylogo"> Syco Sientist Records </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <section id="home">
        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="container-fluid mobile-carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <div class="item active first"><img src="http://blog.allisonjoyce.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ablog186.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="item second"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MLqHuAXasTY/maxresdefault.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="item third"><img src="http://blog.allisonjoyce.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ablog186.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="item fourth"><img src=""><img src="http://www.monopolycity.com/acimages/ac_beach_21_560.gif"></div>

                    <a href="#mycarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#mycarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you try this css:     div#mycarousel .carousel-inner .item{
            padding:0 10%;
        }

Comment: I tried this too. It just added more padding. The carousel still works as before.

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is the when new slides of
>   carouslel move to left the image already present there remains fixed.
>   What I want is that the background image on a div move when the div
>   moves with css transition effects.

In Chrome - Your provided demo is already working as you want.

**But in FireFox the issue is seen**. The issue is because you are using  **fixed** on the images which will keep it fixed, Removing this worked as required in Firefox too.

```
background: url(..) no-repeat fixed;    // remove fixed
```

**Edit 1:** As you said removing `fixed` will break parallax effect you can do this way.

Add another div inside the `.item` div and add image to this div. So now we have a inner div with fixed image, But outer div is free to move.

Below is a working sample

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 320px)");
var mylogo = document.getElementById("mylogo");
if (mq.matches) {
  mylogo.innerHTML = "SSR";
}

function changelogo() {
  return function() {
    if (mq.matches) {

      mylogo.innerHTML = "SSR";
    } else {
      mylogo.innerHTML = "Syco Scientist Records"
    }
  }
}

window.onresize = changelogo();

if (window.matchMedia("(max-height: 420px)").matches) {
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("item")[n].style.backgroundSize = "100% calc(100% - 140px)";
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 60px;
  border-color: #333;
  background-color: #d6d5d5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 14px;
  border-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle > .icon-bar {
  background-color: #333;
}
.navbar ul.navbar-nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li > a {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar ul.nav > li.active > a,
.navbar ul.nav > li.active:hover > a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #d6d5d5;
}
#home {
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 6;
}
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 420px;
}
.mobile-carousel {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .item, .carousel-inner .item > div {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.71, -0.06, .36, 1.35);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.71, -0.06, .36, 1.35);
}
.carousel-inner .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 568px;
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .first > div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_OdCx7pACI9M/TQhDqhnKXgI/AAAAAAAAAH8/kPDpkHpFOnw/s1600/daffy+duck+cartoons+pictures+1.gif) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-inner .second > div{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://www.allgraphics123.com/graphics/cartoons/cartoons123.gif) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-inner .third > div{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/211/WDF_2483525.png) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-inner .fourth > div{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/109/WDF_1525343.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.carousel-control span {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.carousel-control span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -9px;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #777;
  border: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #dcdbdb;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Syco Scientist Records</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="mylogo"> Syco Sientist Records </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="home">
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="container-fluid mobile-carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>

          <div class="item active first"><div></div></div>
          <div class="item second"><div></div></div>
          <div class="item third"><div></div></div>
          <div class="item fourth"><div></div></div>

          <a href="#mycarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/left_Arrow.png"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#mycarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/right_arrow.png"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you mistook me. At present the the image already present there remains **fixed** and gets **opaqued** by the image moving to it's left. For example when _Donald Duck_ moves to the left _Jerry_ remains fixed and is simply covered with _Donald Duck_.

Comment: @user31782 that is not whats happening to me.. I see the image is **not fixed** and it moves to the left as well... Can you confirm if all your scripts and stuffs have loaded properly? check the console for any errors. This is so weird

Comment: @user31782 by the way I can see only 2 images `daffy duck` and `poo` and other two are broken.. so these 2 images are working as expected

Comment: Something's wrong with chrome. I think it is some cross-browser problem.

Comment: @user31782 I am on chrome and its working fine... I have Version 51.0.2704.36 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: @Error404 The problem is with Firefox browser. But I also don't understand why it works in chrome.

Comment: @user31782 I fixed the issue and tested in Firefox, it works now.. have a check and let me know if it helps

Comment: Well that ain't so simple. Removing `fixed` will disallow the parallaxing effect. I want to keep the parallaxing too. Like this: http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io

Comment: The inner div's background image is still fixed with respect to the viewport. So this solution too doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(../img/fav.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
height: 500px;
```

Set the height to your image like `heigth:500px;` or you can use `padding:50px 0;` else it will not display your image on the background until you write anything on that particular div.

Comment: I tried both. The background images still remain fixed.

Comment: put your try code here so we can better understand.